# Writing udev rules - wildcards?

Tags: usb, udev, multiseat

Is it possible to use wildcard characters when writing udev rules? I have multiseat and i want to assign every device (keyboard, mouse etc) that gets connected to a certain USB hub - or even better, a specific port on the front of the PC - to seat1. It's kind of cumbersome to have to redo new rules each time i swap stuff around or don't remember in which USB slot each device was connected.

Using just simple udev rules, as generated by 'loginctl attach' command:

TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_3", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use wildcards in udev rules; this is documented in the [`udev(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html):

> Most of the fields support shell glob pattern matching and
> alternate patterns. The following special characters are
> supported:
>
> "*"
> Matches zero or more characters.
>
> "?"
> Matches any single character.
>
> "[]"
> Matches any single character specified within the brackets.
> For example, the pattern string "tty[SR]" would match either
> "ttyS" or "ttyR". Ranges are also supported via the "-"
> character. For example, to match on the range of all digits,
> the pattern "[0-9]" could be used. If the first character
> following the "[" is a "!", any characters not enclosed are
> matched.
>
> "|"
> Separates alternative patterns. For example, the pattern
> string "abc|x*" would match either "abc" or "x*".

You can see some example rules [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev#Video_device).